# Router is continually broadcasting the same ARP request, with the exact contents

Tags: networking, wireshark, arp

I hope the question is clear and that this is correct place to post the question.

My router is broadcasting the same ARP frame over and over (once every second). It's probably not a big deal, but I want to understand what is going on here.

The request info according to Wireshark is: "who has 10.1.1.111? Tell 10.1.1.1"

Which is weird cause the only occupied IPs are up to 10.1.1.8

Thank you.

Comment: How did you determine that the router was the source of this ARP request and not another device on your network?

Comment: You could assign 10.1.1.111 to a system and see what's trying to get to it.

Comment: @joeqwerty cause the router's ip (the default gateway) is 10.1.1.1, doesn't that mean that this request is coming from the router?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks for clarifying. I didn't want to assume that 10.1.1.1 was your router.

Comment: @DJPon3 Yours should be an answer really.

Comment: @syneticon-dj done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is that something is trying to send traffic through your router to 10.1.1.111 and the router is trying to locate that address on your network.

Whether that's the result of something else on your network, a bug in some of the code on the router, or external traffic that a rule on your router is attempting to forward is now open for debate - and wfaulk's comment looks like a decent next step to settling that debate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the fact that this issue never stops (all day long, everyday) makes it more likely that it is a bug in the router? If so are there any simple ways to fix that?            and yes it's an old router, its latest update was from 2009, no newer firmwares since then.

Comment: I would say yes, and bugs in home router s/w aren't uncommon (*my comment on another SOHO router question: I swear to god it must be mandatory to show up to work drunk for people in that field, based on some of the stuff they churn out*）. It could equally well be another device on your network, though not of course if you've changed everything else except the router over those 3 years!